# Proof that (Z3, +) is isomorphic C3, and (Z3, +) is a proper subgroup of S3

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I was wondering how to prove that ($\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, +), the group of integers under addition is *isomorphic* to $C_{3}$, the third *cyclic group* such that $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \cong C_{3}$.

Also that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a *proper subgroup* of $S_{3}$, the third group of *permutations*.

I understand that one can express ${C}_{3} = \{e, a, a^{2}\}$ where $a = \exp(2\pi i /3)$ and $a^{3} = e$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{3} = \{e, 1, 2\}$ but I am unsure how to go about explicitly expressing the isomorphism.

It must be possible to define a *homomorphism* such that $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{3} \longmapsto C_{3}$, where

$\phi(g_{1}\cdot g_{2}) = \phi(g_{1})\star\phi(g_{2})$, $g_{1}, g_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

Comment: Your title is incorrect

Comment: You mean that $\Bbb Z_3$ is **isomorphic to** a proper subgroup of $S_3$ ...

Comment: Since you wrote "$(\Bbb Z_3,+)$", then "$\phi(g_{1}\cdot g_{2})$" should more properly be written "$\phi(g_{1}+g_{2})$".

Answer (score 2):

Just consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_3\longrightarrow C_3$ such that $f(0)=1$, that $f(1)=a$, and that $f(2)=a^2$. In other words, $f(n)=a^n$.

And a natural injective map from $\mathbb{Z}_3$ into $S_3$ is $n\mapsto(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)^n$.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my question.  Does this make more sense now?

Comment: @BenLeather I have adapted my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: For the second part, I was looking to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_{3}$.

Comment: @BenLeather That is *not* part of your question. The word “normal” wasn't used before. If you have another question, please post it as such.